# Getting The SourceSet 'instrumentTest' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin when i merged branch

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting below error **only when** I try to merge my branch with the main branch in my project.

> The SourceSet 'instrumentTest' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin.

And when I reset my branch to the last commit, it works.

This was happening in **Android Studio** Version **3.1.2** and it's still there in current version **3.2** also.

This issue has already taken a lot of my time.

I tried to fix it by replacing **instrumentTest** with **androidTest** answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511200/the-sourceset-instrumenttest-is-not-recognized-by-the-android-gradle-plugin) but it's not working for me.

[image]

This error leads to the above **Unable to resolve dependency** errors

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would be the lines from your `build.gradle` file that are failing, plus the complete Gradle output. If these lines are in your `dependencies` closure, and they represent dependencies for instrumented tests, use `androidTestImplementation` to pull them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, I found the answer to this problem.

After reading the errors carefully, I came to know that the problem is there in my lib module.
And the error was not actually the one mentioned in **Title**.

Then I did below changes in the code.

I tried upgrating **gradle version** from `3.2.0`  to `3.3.0-alpha13` and 
**gradle distribution version** from `4.6` to `4.10.1` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Earlier my `lib/build.gradle` containing only `release` **buildType**.
So I added same **buildTypes** which were in `app/build.gradle`.

Now my lib/build.gradle and app/build.gradle have same buildTypes

**`lib/build.gradle`**
[image]

**`app/build.gradle`**
[image]

And after syncing & building the project, I got rid of these errors(errors from image; **Unable to resolve dependency**).

Hope this will help someone.
Thanks.